# How do i know if install isn't malicious

Tags: macos, security

I just got my first osx device (a late 2012 mac mini), the last owner said he did a fresh install of yosemite. Is there a way to check that he didn't install any mallware/spyware?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't be 100% sure unless you do it yourself (with an Apple provided DVD or DMG).

Comment: Couldn't they just use OS X Recovery instead of needing a disk? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314